# how can i make each html/css into a separate block?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have one box on the left, center and right- however it's all connected to the body in css. i am not sure what i am doing wrong, as i am new and this is the first time i am trying to create my own code from scratch vs copy one i have found. thank you!

```
HTML:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="portfolio.css">


<div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="top-container"></div>
    <div class="mid-container"></div> 
    <div class="bottom-container"></div>
    </div>

    </body>


CSS:

body{
    background-color: darkolivegreen;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;

}

.top-container{
    display: flex;
    border-style: solid;
    background-color:white;
    margin:5px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;

}
.mid-container{
    display:flex;
    border-style:solid;
    background-color: teal;
    margin:5px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;

}

.bottom-container{
     display:flex;
    justify-items: flex-end;
    border-style: solid;
    background-color: thistle;
    margin:5px;
    height: 200px;
    width:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would pull the `.header` outside of `.container` (and make it a semantic `header` element), since it will only interfere with what you're trying to accomplish using `flexbox`. Using `justify-content: space-between` on the `flex` parent, you will position the three children on the left, center, and right regions.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content), regarding `justify-content: space-between`:

> Distribute items evenly. The first item is flush with the start, the last is flush with the end

One thing to remember with `flexbox`, and also `grid`, is that you usually set these types of positioning rules in the parent element, and the children do as they're told.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
 
/*
 For the sake of the demo, set all immediate children to
 have a one pixel red border 
*/
.container > * {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="top-container">one</div>
  <div class="mid-container">two</div>
  <div class="bottom-container">three</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to add `display: flex;` in every box. 
what you can do is just add `display:flex;`,  `justify-content: flex-end;` and to other box add `margin-right: auto;`  both first and second box.

Here's the code. Let me know if it doesn't work for you.

```css
        
body{
    background-color: darkolivegreen;

}
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.top-container{
    border-style: solid;
    background-color:white;
    margin:5px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.mid-container{
    border-style:solid;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: teal;
    margin:5px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.bottom-container{
    border-style: solid;
    background-color: thistle;
    margin:5px;
    height: 200px;
    width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="top-container"></div>
    <div class="mid-container"></div> 
    <div class="bottom-container"></div>
    </div>
```